# GoogleAdd framework failed in ARM7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm7

I am using google [image]

Framework search path i gave the proper search path for this library.

but while build i am getting this error:

[image]

Where i did mistake please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add essential frameworks also like

```
AdSupport

AudioToolbox

AVFoundation

CoreGraphics

CoreMedia

CoreTelephony

EventKit

EventKitUI

MessageUI

StoreKit

SystemConfiguration
```

Its described [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start)

Comment: its shows how careless i was :(,need to develop me more more thanks bro.

Comment: This same thing happened to me also ;)

Comment: ha ha any way your experience helped me to out ;)